# Using my C++/Qt Library (DLL) in Visual Basic

Tags: c++, .net, qt, dll

I wrote a small library (dll) in C++ using Qt. I made it so it is easier to use QSocket stuff for TCP Client/Server.

I know it is possible to use C++ dlls but I have no idea for Qt. How will I be able to connect those signals I made in Qt from Visual Basic?

Thanks.

Comment: i tried something like that as well and found myself lost. to use signal/slot, you have a `QEventLoop` running, so the dll must do that.

as well as when a signal is emitted, i think you have no matching api in vb to `connect` a slot to it. i used containers to store the values and have getters to access the computed values in the container